# Saving data into dynamodb using unauthenticated arn from android doesn't work

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to save a test record to amazon dynamodb table from Android.

```
    Context mContext = this.getApplicationContext();

    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            mContext, // get the context for the current activity
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "us-east-1:dsfhjhsd-sdfsfds-sdffds-dsffs",
            "arn:aws:iam::7777777777:role/Cognito_CustMobAnalyticsUnauth_DefaultRole",
            "YOUR AUTHENTICATED ARN HERE",
            Regions.US_EAST_1
    );

    try {

        AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(cognitoProvider);
        //ddb.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddb);

        androTest mytest = new androTest();
        mytest.setMyKey("testKey-1");

        try {
            mapper.save(mytest);

        } catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
            Log.e("CustomError", "---> " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // This will catch any exception, because they are all descended from Exception
        Log.e("CustomError", "---> " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        Log.e("CustomError", "---> " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I am getting the following message while executing and data is not updated.
I am using unauthenticated arn.

```
 D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
 D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider﹕ No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences
 E/CustomError﹕ ---> null
 E/CustomError﹕ ---> null
```

Following is the role policies

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement":[{
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Action":"cognito-sync:*",
    "Resource":["*"]
    }]
}

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmtxxxxxx",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
        "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
        "dynamodb:GetItem",
        "dynamodb:PutItem",
        "dynamodb:Query",
        "dynamodb:Scan",
        "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
        "dynamodb:UpdateTable"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:663633636363:table/androTest"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Following is the trust policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:chgsdhg0-sdds-sdsd-7687668c05"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "unauthenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Stack Trace

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
            at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
            at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
            at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
            at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
            at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
            at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
            at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getId(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.getIdentityId(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.refresh(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSBasicCognitoIdentityProvider.refresh(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(Unknown Source)
            at com.multixlabs.fdintcalculator.MainActivity.updateDynamodbAnalyticsTable(MainActivity.java:149)
            at com.multixlabs.fdintcalculator.MainActivity.btnCalculateClick(MainActivity.java:174)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: the problem is `No valid credentials found`, so check this link, if it can help you fix the issue: [
Using the Amazon Cognito Credentials Provider](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxR1UCU80YEJJZ/Using-the-Amazon-Cognito-Credentials-Provider)

Comment: Thanks BMW. That link is for authenticated users. Here I am doing unauthenticated.

Comment: is `no valid credential` same meaning of unauthenticated?  the error you faced is before unauthenticated/authenticated, it is stopped at beginning.

Comment: The no valid credential message isn't an error, it's an informational message saying there are no credentials currently cached. Could you provide a bit more detail on what exception is being caught, namely the stacktrace? It'd help narrow things down.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - Stack trace added in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem it's a network issue. As of Android 3.x (I believe) making network calls on the main/UI thread causes this exception to be thrown. If you try saving it to dynamo asynchronously, common practice is using an Async Task, that error should go away.